# How to make GTK focus_out event fire based on child widgets recursively or how to check if none of children has focus

Tags: c++, gtk3, gtkmm, gtkmm3

I have the following widget structure, I want to do some task when none of the child widgets of `Gtk::Box` has the keyboard focus. A user can type in search entry and Listbox contains suggestions.

```
Gtk::Box
|
|-- SearchBar
|   |--SearchEntry
|-- ListBox
    |--(many list box rows)
```

I am using `gtkmm-3.0`

**Heres what I have tried**

1. Attaching focus out event to Gtk::Box, didn't work. It never has focus
2. Attaching focus_out to SearchEntry and ListBox, when any of rows get focused the event is fired(I want it to happen only when none of children has focus)

Comment: i don't know if i got your question properly or not.. so when the widget has no focus and the user still types you want to get the input corret? if its like that why not use https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-grab-focus?

Comment: I am using focus not to take input in this case. It's just that if none of the child widgets has focused the widget should be hidden @SivaGuru

Comment: so you want to be notified when your((Gtk::Box
)) widget lose notification. could you share with me some working code? i will see what went wrong and try to provide a solution
.